# How to get column names where column value is null in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

For a given table, I need an SQL (SQL Server 2008 Query) which can get all the column names having column value as `NULL`.

Comment: Column names are null? I assume you want to return all columns where the records are null?

Comment: should any value of the column or all  values of the column be null?

Comment: Or another alternative is that you want to know all of the columns which can *accept* nulls. You need to edit your question and be more clear on what you're actually trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work, it is filtered by database, schema and table. It retrieves column name when a `NULL` value exists in any row of a column (but that's just a minor consideration that you can play with and set it any way you want in a query contained in an `@sql` variable by changing `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` conditions):

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100) = 'yourDB'
DECLARE @schemaName VARCHAR(100) = 'yourSchema'
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100) = 'yourTable'
DECLARE @result TABLE (col VARCHAR(4000))

SELECT  @dbname dbname
        ,t.name tbl
        ,c.name col
INTO    #temp
FROM    sys.columns c
JOIN    sys.tables t ON 
        t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE   c.is_nullable = 1
AND     t.name = @tableName

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
STUFF(
(
    SELECT  'UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @dbname + '.' + @schemaName + '.' + tbl + ' WHERE ' + col + ' IS NULL) THEN '''+ @schemaName  + '.' + tbl + '.' + col+''' END AS NULL_Value_Exists '
    FROM    #temp
    FOR     XML PATH('')
), 1, 10, '   ')

INSERT @result
EXEC(@sql)

SELECT  *
FROM    @result
WHERE   col IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #temp
```

If you would like to get all the columns of all tables from a certain schema that satisfy given conditions you wouldn't even have to specify table name and you would simply join `sys.schemas`. That would give you a list of all columns from all tables on a specified schema that contain `NULL` in any row, only thing required would be to change the first query into:

```
SELECT  @dbname dbname
        ,t.name tbl
        ,c.name col
INTO    #temp
FROM    sys.columns c
JOIN    sys.tables t ON 
        t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas s ON 
        s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   c.is_nullable = 1
AND     s.name =@schemaName
```

Comment: Great, you're welcome, if you find the answer most useful you can mark it as correct.